# Tipp10 won't launch in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I downloaded the `.deb` from the official website [Tipp10](http://www.tipp10.com/en/download) and installed it via the Ubuntu Software center. However the app fails to launch from dash, launcher and the terminal. Terminal gives me this message when I try to launch from the it:

```
./tipp10: error while loading shared libraries: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to rectify this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: same problem with 14.10 the ans doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this from terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libsm6 libsm6:i386 -y
```

That should fix `libsm` at least whether you are on 32- or 64-bit. And then try running Tipp10 from `/usr/share/tipp10`

Comment: it seems libsm was included in the ia32-libs package. Thanks for your help

Comment: what about the answer for same question but in 14.10 ur ans doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This is Tipp10 software package bug - it seems they forgot to include **libsm6** package in depends :(
You should **install libsm6 package** with Ubuntu Software center.
See [packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libSM.so.6&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libSM.so.6&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise)

Comment: Ubuntu Software Centre indicates that that package 'libsm6' is already installed

Comment: Maybe you use 64-bit Ubuntu operating system?
tipp10_debian_v2-1-0.deb package is very bad quality - executable is 32 bit, but in deb package architecture is set wrongly to "all" :( Report this to author of this software: 

~$ file /usr/share/tipp10/tipp10
/usr/share/tipp10/tipp10: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped

Comment: You are right I'm on a 64bit system. I will definitely report this bug

Comment: libsm6 is in the ia32-libs package. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issues on Ubuntu 17.04, but managed to resolve them by installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install  libxcursor1:i386  libsm6:i386  libxrandr2:i386  libxi6:i386   libxinerama1:i386  libfreetype6:i386  libfontconfig1:i386  libglib2.0-0:i386  libstdc++6:i386
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Schreibtrainer/

Comment: +1 this worked for me while other answers didn't.